# Unit-testing EF6 non-query operations

Tags: entity-framework, unit-testing, mocking, moq, entity-framework-6

I'm using Entity Framework 6 and I have a class with a method that adds some records to the database:

```
interface IRecordsContext
{
    DbSet<MyRecord> MyRecords { get; }
    int SaveChanges();
}

class MyService
{
    public MyService(IRecordsContext ctx)
    {
        _context = ctx;
    }

    private readonly IRecordsContext _context;

    public void AddRecords(int count)
    {
        _context.MyRecords.AddRange(
            from id in Enumerable.Range(1, count)
            select new MyRecord { Value = id }
        );

        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Now I am using Moq library to create unit tests:

```
void AddRecords_ShouldAddThemToDatabase()
{
    var contextMock = new Mock<IRecordsContext>();
    // ...
}
```

How can I write a test that ensures that the `Records` collection now contains 10 extra records using mocks, without modifying any actual database?

I'm also eager to listen to opinions on whether this architecture is un-testable and how it should be refactored.

Answer (score 0):

Have one variable that is set to `.Count()` of the `DbSet` before the method is run, and check that against the value of `.Count()` afterwards.

Comment: I'm afraid this won't work. I'm not using the actual `RecordsContext`, but instead create a mock of it using the `Moq` library. I only know how to create read-only mocks of `DbSets`.